# Add up monthly values base on definition on quarter

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

Trying to Add up monthly values base on definition on which month belongs to which quarter (so definition can be update):

[image]

I'm trying to use inner join to achieve but failed:

```
SELECT qr, sum(price)
INTO Table3
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
on Table1.mth = Table2.mth
INNER JOIN Table3
on Table2.qr = Table3.qr
```

Also I'm not sure if an additional column in Table1 (qr) will make things easier?

Comment: you need to add `GROUP BY qr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table3 already have those 4 rows to start with and you just want to update the prices in table3 to reflect the price of each quarter you can use this query:

```
UPDATE Table3 T3, 
  (SELECT T2.qr,sum(T1.price) as quarterly_price
   FROM Table1 T1
   INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.mth = T2.mth
   GROUP BY T2.qr) AS Result
SET T3.price = Result.quarterly_price
WHERE T3.qr = Result.qr;
```

[sqlfiddle to Update Table3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fad16/1)

If table3 doesn't have those 4 rows and you want to insert them, use this query:

```
INSERT INTO Table3
  SELECT T2.qr,sum(T1.price) as quarterly_price
   FROM Table1 T1
   INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.mth = T2.mth
   GROUP BY T2.qr;
```

[sqlfiddle to Insert into Table3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f364ff/1)

**EDIT:** Tin I modify a little from your code and this works fine in Access's query:

```
SELECT Table2.qr,sum(Table1.price) as Price_new
INTO Table3
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.mth = Table2.mth
GROUP BY Table2.qr;
```

Comment: Thanks Tin, I tried running the code with the sqlfiddle link and works, however it doesn't work with when I try the query in Access, is it something entirely diff?

Comment: i don't know what kind of SQL access uses...maybe there's minor differences in syntax